# Why is Firestore's 'doc.get('time').toMillis' producing a null Type Error?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, redux, react-redux

In a react-native application, I call an action sends data to firebase. but after the call, I get an error whose source seems to be with the way the snapshot listener is working. the add-msg action more or less looks like this:

create data:

```
const addMsg = (msg, convoIds) => {
    console.log('Firestore Write: (actions/conversation) => addMsg()');

    return firebase.firestore().collection('messages').add({
        time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        sender: msg.sender,
        receiverToken: msg.receiverToken,
        sessionId: msg.sessionId,
        read: false,
        charged: false,
        userConvos: [ convoIds.sender, convoIds.receiver ],
        content: {
            type: 'msg',
            data: msg.text
        }
    });
};
```

I also have a snapshot listener (that executes in componentDidMount) that populates a redux store with messages from a collection in firestore. the snapshot listener looks like:

```
export const getMessages = (convoId) => {
    const tmp = convoId == null ? '' : convoId;
    return (dispatch) => {
        console.log('Firestore Read (Listener): (actions/conversation) => getMessages()');
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection('messages')
                .where('userConvos', 'array-contains', tmp)
                .orderBy('time')
                .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
                    const messages = [];
                    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                        const msg = doc.data();
                        msg.docId = doc.id;
                        msg.time = doc.get('time').toMillis();

                        messages.push(msg);
                    });
                    dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_MSGS, payload: messages });
                    resolve();
                });
        });
    };
};
```

the corresponding reducer that populates a flatList in the same screen component which looks like:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    messages: []
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.LOAD_MSGS:
            return {
                messages: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return { ...state };
    }
};
```

*Problem:* once the data sends, I immediately get an error `TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'doc.get('time').toMillis'`. if I reload the application, navigate back to the screen in question, the msg appears, and so does the time data. So my guess is something is happening with the delay in the promissory nature of firebase calls, and the delay causes a null initialization of the time value, but its long enough to crash the application.

*Question:* what is actually happening behind the scenes here and how can I prevent this error?

Comment: Is doc.get('time') null?

Comment: @LajosArpad when I access it in the screen component, it displays the time

Comment: If I were you, I would, just before the line of ```msg.time = doc.get('time').toMillis();``` do an experiment in the form of ```console.log(doc.get('time').toMillis())```. You will see whether that's the thing which is null or not. This is a key information that you need in order to solve your problem.

Comment: @LajosArpad already have. all the times get logged

Comment: Can you add a verbatim quote of the exact error message you get to the question?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you encounter is caused by the `onSnapshot()` listener firing from the local Firestore cache during a small window where the value of  [`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue#servertimestamp) is considered pending and is treated as `null` by default. Once the server accepts your changes, it responds with all the new values for the timestamps and triggers your `onSnapshot()` listener again.

Without care, this may cause your app to 'flicker' as it stamps the data out twice.

To change the behaviour of pending timestamps, you can pass a [`SnapshotOptions`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotOptions) object as the last argument to [`doc.data()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#data) and [`doc.get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot#get) as appropriate.

The following code, instructs the Firebase SDK to estimate the new timestamp values based on the local clock.

```js
const estimateTimestamps = {
  serverTimestamps: 'estimate'
}

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const msg = doc.data(); // here msg.time = null
  msg.docId = doc.id;
  msg.time = doc.get('time', estimateTimestamps).toMillis(); // update msg.time to set value (or estimate if not available)

  messages.push(msg);
});
```

If you want to show that your message is still being written to the database, you could check if `msg.time` is `null` just before estimating the timestamp.

```js
const estimateTimestamps = {
  serverTimestamps: 'estimate'
}

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  const msg = doc.data(); // here msg.time = null when pending
  msg.docId = doc.id;
  msg.isPending = msg.time === null;
  msg.time = doc.get('time', estimateTimestamps).toMillis(); // update msg.time to set value (or estimate if not available)

  messages.push(msg);
});
```

If you want to ignore these intermediate 'local' events in favour of waiting for the server's full response, you would use:

```js
.onSnapshot({includeMetadataChanges: true}, (querySnapshot) => {
  if (querySnapshot.metadata.fromCache && querySnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites) {
    return; // ignore cache snapshots where new data is being written
  }
  const messages = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    const msg = doc.data();
    msg.docId = doc.id;
    msg.time = doc.get('time', estimateTimestamps).toMillis();

    messages.push(msg);
  });
  dispatch({ type: types.LOAD_MSGS, payload: messages });
  resolve();
});
```

In the above code block, note that I also checked [`querySnapshot.metadata.hasPendingWrites`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata#haspendingwrites) before ignoring the event so that when you first load up your app, it will print out any cached information immediately. Without this, you will show an empty message list until the server responds. Most sites will print out any cached data while showing a throbber at the top of the page until the server responds with any new data.

Comment: As an added note, don't forget to correctly dispose of your listeners! The call to `onSnapshot()` returns an unsubscribe function that your should store and call when your component is disposed. e.g. `const unsubMessageListener = firebase...onSnapshot(...);` and when disposed call `unsubMessageListener()`.

Comment: wonderfully insightful information. however after attempting all three options listed, I'm still encountering the same error

Comment: That sounds like the `time` field is missing/set to null on 1 or more documents in your collection which could be caused by saving an entry in your `messages` array back to the database without the proper timestamp (and thus `msg.time` would now be `null`) such as when editing a message. Try this instead of the `msg.time = ...` line: `const timestamp = doc.get('time', estimateTimestamps); if (timestamp) { msg.time = timestamp.toMillis(); } else { console.error(doc.id + ' is missing "time" field!'); /* debugger; */ }`. If you get a hit, uncomment `debugger;` and take a closer look.

Comment: yes the else condition was execute, but when I check the relevant document the "time" field is there?

Comment: ill award bounty since you're the only that took time to help, even though I haven't fixed the error :'(

Comment: @Jim Message me on the [Firebase Slack](https://firebase.community) and we can see if we can find out what's up.